# Sapply function confuses me

Tags: r

It's a basic question and sure, there are a lot of examples in google.. but I just do not understand this small bunch of code..

```
V <- seq(50, 350, by = 1)

> VK
    Voltage^0     Voltage^1     Voltage^2     Voltage^3 
-1.014021e+01  9.319875e-02 -2.738749e-04  2.923875e-07 

plot(x = V, exp(exp(sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK)), type = "l"); grid()
```

I tried to get behind this after playing a lot with the function itself but.. I cannot apply my ideas to this certain line.
As far as I got I believe I can tell: sapply is a function that applies the body for each element of a vector or list or something similar. In this case this is V.
The point that confuses me is the "0:3" part (which seems to be amount of elements of VK) and the end of the function %*% VK. When I do the very same on my own with different numbers than VK is summed up and then used as a coefficient for exp(exp(V^x)). But here in this case this makes no sense.
Furthermore: By googling I always read that sapply yields a vector. Due to the fact that the code above generates a plot this is a 2D-vector as result?

Comment: `sapply()` is running `V^0`, then `V^1`,then `V^2`, then `V^3`, then putting the results in a matrix.  Then `%*%` is multiplying that matrix by `VK`.  Forget google for a minute, and read the official R documentation via `help(sapply)`.

Comment: @RichScriven Ahh..  thanks a lot! That's very unvisceral.. :) Can you also please tell me why this only works when I demand "(..sapply(0:3,..)" and not "(..sapply(0:2,..)" or something different?

Comment: Because `length(0:2)` and `length(VK)` are not the same. For `%*%`, the matrices must be conformable.

Comment: @RichScriven I know that the number of columns of the matrix must be the same as the rows of the vector but V is only one column. Or not? Or is this something different here?

Comment: 0:3 is the same as `c(0,1,2,3)`, so that the output of `sapply(0:3, f)` is `f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3)`, which has four elements. If you do 0:2, there will only be three elements, and for matrix multiplication with `VK`, which has four elements, you need one more.

Comment: @Ben - Yes, but the result from `sapply(0:2, ...)` will only be 3 columns.  When you try to multiply that by `VK`, which is length 4, it will fail.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it just has to be as many rows as the vector meaning one cannot limit the vector itself for the multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x)
> sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x)
       [,1] [,2]   [,3]     [,4]
  [1,]    1   50   2500   125000
  [2,]    1   51   2601   132651
  [3,]    1   52   2704   140608
```

As stated in the comments, sapply generates a matrix (`301x4`) where each column represents `V^0`, `V^1`,`V^2`, and `V^3`. Then, it is multiplied by VK (`4x1`). This will generate a vector (`301x1`).

```
> sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK
               [,1]
  [1,] -6.128411312
  [2,] -6.060636871
  [3,] -5.993320708
```

After these steps, you apply the exponential function twice to your new vector. This new vector contains your y-values for your plot.

If you wanted to apply "(..sapply(0:2,..)" instead of "(..sapply(0:3,..)", then change VK to this:

```
VK <- c(-1.014021e+01,  9.319875e-02, -2.738749e-04)
names(VK) <- c( "Voltage^0",     "Voltage^1",     "Voltage^2")
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it now completely!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing multiple things in one line. I guess you are getting lost in the different parts on 1 line where like 5 things happen at the same time.

```
plot(x = V, exp(exp(sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK)), type = "l"); grid()
```

First off, the main part is `plot(x, y, type = "l")`. This just plots a vector `x` against a vector `y`. In your case, `y` is `exp(exp(sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK))`.

An easier and prettier way to have written the code, would've been:

```
inside_of_y <- sapply(0:3, function(x){ V^x %*% VK })
y_variable  <- exp(exp(inside_of_y))

plot(x = V, y = y_variable, type = "l")    
grid()
```

The first line is probably still messing with you a bit. In essence, `sapply` is just a `for`-loop. It is built up of two ingredients: `part1` and `part2`.

`part1` is an object with multiple elements, like a data.frame or a vector (here: `part1` is equal to `c(0, 1, 2, 3)`). The elements inside this object are used as arguments for `part2`. In this particular case, you defined a custom function as `part2`. In this custom function, you take `V` to the power of `x` and multiply the result with the matrix `VK`. The tricky part is that `x` is equal to `0` in the first iteration, `1` in the second iteration, ..., and `3` in the last one. You just looped through `0:3`, which is `part1` of your `sapply(part1, part2)`.

So `inside_of_y` now contains 4 elements. Then we just proceed with plotting `x` against `y` with the `plot(x, y)` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Just for illustration, here is what the code looks like when translated into a `for` loop.

```
V <- seq(50, 350, by = 1)

VK <- c("Voltage^0" = -1.014021e+01,
        "Voltage^1" = 9.319875e-02,
        "Voltage^2" = -2.738749e-04,
        "Voltage^3" = 2.923875e-07)

coef <- matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = length(V))

for(x in 0:3){
  coef[, x + 1] <- V^x 
}

Y <- exp(exp(coef %*% VK))

plot(V, Y, type = "l"); grid()
```

It works because `sapply` is an over achiever that tries not to fail by returning a matrix if it can't return a vector.